# find numeric id names for all <td> elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find all the solely numeric <td> element id's in all of the <td> elements where the id's are the same as their contents.

The need is to find which <td> elements are numeric and which are alphanumeric and then use that to edit the displayed info.

I must know the number that the numeric ones used to read to generate the javascript on click link that it will make.

I do have jQuery.

Comment: Hm... something as simple as "get all tds -> for each - get id & check it" will not suffice?

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

```
var tdList = $('#tableid td').filter(function() {
  return !isNaN(this.id);
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q2Uv/)

The only potential problem is that an id like this `-1.23` would be included, it's up to you to decide if this is a problem or not.

**EDIT**

If only positive integers are allowed, you could do something like this

```
var tdList = $('td').filter(function() {
  return /^\d+$/.test(this.id);
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/7rtXv/)

Thanks @Sly and @jods

Comment: @user1495129: I don't know how you have to use it, I'm afraid that without more context can't provide more information.

Comment: Also, you can use `return !isNaN(this.id) && this.id >= 0` in the filter if you want to get rid of negative numbers.

Comment: @user1495129 check Claudio's nicely made "[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q2Uv/)" for an example. In that demo the "list" object will contain all the numeric tds. You can perform jquery operations like `list.hide()` on that object.

Comment: Other example of id that would match: '4e3' (would also pass the modification in Sly comment). Based on the same code you could replace the isNaN test by something more specific like /^\d+$/.test(this.id) if you want integers only.